# Any simple, free-to-download IDEs for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, ide, text-editor

I want to find a free JavaScript IDE (Mac & Windows) that is as simple as installing the app and being able to run code on the debugger or IDE's console. I am basically looking for a JavaScript equivalent of Python's Enthought Canopy or Pycharm. Applications like WebStorm require payment. Applications Emacs and Eclipse Che need text for them to set up (I am not familiar with this way of installing). Other Applications—when it comes to running code—are simply just hard to navigate like Atom and Brackets where I can even find a button to run code.

Answer (score 2):

You seem new in Js so ... https://code.visualstudio.com/ it's the most loved editor based on the last **StackOverflow's survey**

It's kinda open source so you won't need to pay anything, supported by Microsoft.